# How to save entities in table with unique constraint

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I work with Spring Boot and have 2 PostgreSQL tables: USERS and CITIES. `FOREIGN KEY (USERS.city_id) REFERENCES CITIES (id)`. CITIES has an unique constraint for city name field. I receive an object in the `@PostMapping` method of the controller and try to save it via service layer. All is fine while I don't send an object with same city name field, and I don't know how to solve it. Postman JSON example:

```
*1st attempt*
{
    "name": "JHON",
    "city": {
        "name": **"MOSCOW"**
    }
} ---> ALL OK
```

[image]

```
*2nd attempt*
{
    "name": "TOM",
    "city": {
        "name": **"MOSCOW"**
    }
}--->**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cities_name_key"
  Details: The key "(name) = (MOSCOW)" already exists.**
```

***Entity:***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;
}
```

*Tables:*

```
cities
    id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name TEXT UNIQUE

users
    id      SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name    VARCHAR(10),
    city_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT users_cities_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES cities (id)
```

and Service

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public User getUser(Long id){
        return userRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

    public User saveUser(User user){
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I don't know how to solve it." - How to solve what? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: How to add from controller new USER "name": "TOM", "city": {"name": "MOSCOW"} if "MOSCOW " is already exist in CITY table and UNICAL. For example I want to add JHON, TOM, BILL with city MOSCOW. First time with JHON all be ok, but I get an error that city name MOSCOW is unical when I send TOM , BILL etc that's a problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer for question.
So if you have fields with unique constraints in the your tables, you have to define a constructor inside the entity for the primary key field. And don't hope that Lombok will do it. It means that annotation like @AllArgsConstructor does not help for this case.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;


    //add this *********************
    public City(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
    }
}
```